# While Loop causing freezing issues....any alternative looping methods?

Tags: javascript, android

I have some code for a web application that syncs data events to the android version of the app. The problem I run into is it uses a SETINTERVAL cmdlet to repeatedly return a location value. I was able to set a timeout cmdlet (SETTIMEOUT) instead to only return the value once, but the problem with that is that if I set it too low, it doesnt return a value, if I set it too high, it wont return the value until the SETTIMEOUT time is done. Im trying to get the CURRENTLOCATION functions value THEN apply the value once it has returned the value. I tried using a

```
while (!location){}
```

but when that sends the data events to my phone and I open up that record, the app freezes. Is there an alternative method to loop back to the beginning of the function and call it again until the (var location) condition is met?

Here is the code:

```
ON('load-record', function(event) {
  var updateLocationInfo = function() {
    // get the current device location
    var location = CURRENTLOCATION();

    // if there is no location, display a special message
    if (!location) {
      SETLABEL('gps_info', 'GPS Coordinates');
      return;
    }

    // format the display of the location data
    var message = [
      'Latitude: ' + location.latitude,
      'Longitude: ' + location.longitude
    ].join('\n');

    // set the label property of the label on the form
    SETLABEL('gps_info', 'GPS Coordinates');
    SETVALUE('gps_info', location)
  };

  // go ahead and update it now...
  updateLocationInfo();

  // ... and every 3 seconds
  SETINTERVAL(updateLocationInfo, 00001);
});
```

Comment: `Is there an alternative method to loop back to the beginning of the function and call it again until the (var location) condition is met?` short: Without the freeze? No. Seems like you can only poll. What's in `CURRENTLOCATION`?

Comment: Current location is an API call that fulcrum uses to grab the current GPS information when called in the android app.

https://developer.fulcrumapp.com/data-events/reference/currentlocation/

Answer (score 0):

> Current location is an API call that fulcrum uses to grab the current GPS information when called in the android app.

OK, so it's a blackbox that returns the location if available, otherwise it doesn't. Then all you can do is poll and hope that you eventually get the value.

```
ON('load-record', function (event) {
  var attempts = 0;

  var updateLocationInfo = function () {
    // get the current device location
    var location = CURRENTLOCATION();

    if (location) {
      // format the display of the location data
      var message = [
        'Latitude: ' + location.latitude,
        'Longitude: ' + location.longitude
      ].join('\n');

      // set the label property of the label on the form
      SETLABEL('gps_info', 'GPS Coordinates');
      SETVALUE('gps_info', location)

    } else if (attempts++ < 500) { // try it for approx 5s
      SETLABEL('gps_info', 'GPS Coordinates');
      SETTIMEOUT(updateLocationInfo, 10);

    } else {
      // you have to know when it's time to stop.

      // sry, didn't get the value
      // display your special message
    }
  };

  // go ahead and try it now...
  updateLocationInfo();
});
```

A slightly more sophisticated approach could be:

```
ON('load-record', function (event) {
  // try to get the value for 5 seconds
  var endTime = Date.now() + 5000;
  // start with a 10ms interval
  var delay = 10;
  var updateLocationInfo = function () {
    if (location) {
      // ...
    } else if (Date.now() < endTime) {
      // slow down the polling, but cap it at max. 500ms interval
      SETTIMEOUT(updateLocationInfo, Math.min(delay *= 1.15, 500));
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  }

  updateLocationInfo();
})
```

That way you don't poll the entire 5 seconds every 10ms. Start off eager
in the hope that you'll succeed quickly, but slow down to not create that much load if it takes a bit longer.

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank You. I actually changed the 5000 to 10000 and added the variable information under var updateloactioninfo and the message part as well and it works great! 





'var location = CURRENTLOCATION();  
    if (location) {  
        
      var message = [  
        'Latitude: ' + location.latitude,  
        'Longitude: ' + location.longitude  
      ].join('\n');  
  
      SETVALUE('gps_info', message);  
  
    } else if (Date.now() < endTime) {'